# Locator not working on Android 6.0 +

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a problem with Locator in my app. I have service that use User current location and based on it it show pins from closest marketplaces. It works without problems on Android bellows 6.0 but on 6.0 it can't get user locations. I assume because of new permission system in it.

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.locator_fragment, container, false);


    // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it

    mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
    map = mapView.getMap();
    map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(final Location location) {
            Latitude= location.getLatitude();
            Longitude=  location.getLongitude();
            float distance = location.distanceTo(location);
            Location locationzoom = map.getMyLocation();
            LatLng mapCenter = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            if(!didSetLocation) {
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = CameraPosition.builder()
                        .target(mapCenter)
                        .zoom(13)
                        .bearing(80)
                        .build();

                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition),
                        2000, null);
                didSetLocation=true;
            }
            if ((lastcall!=null)?(location.distanceTo(lastcall)>1000):true)
            {
                map.clear();
                NetworkSDK.getInstance().getCoordinates(Latitude, Longitude, new Callback<List<Coordinate>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<Coordinate>> call, Response<List<Coordinate>> response) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.body().size(); i++) {
                            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(new LatLng(response.body().get(i).getLatitude(), response.body().get(i).getLongitude()))
                                    .title(response.body().get(i).getName()));

                        }
                        lastcall=location;

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<Coordinate>> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.errorNoconnection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            }
        }

    });

    Location mLastLocation;
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return v;
    }
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.isTrafficEnabled();

    // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls

    MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());

    // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
    return v;
}
```

How should I give user choice to grant permission for app?

Comment: try the updated answer i have made some changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 1;

     void checkPremission() {
            //select which permission you want
            final String permission = Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
                // if in fragment use getActivity()
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ActivityName.this, permission)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ActivityName.this, permission)) {

                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityName.this, new String[]{permission}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                }
            } else {
                // you have permission go ahead

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION:
                    final int numOfRequest = grantResults.length;
                    final boolean isGranted = numOfRequest == 1
                            && PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == grantResults[numOfRequest - 1];
                    if (isGranted) {
                        // you have permission go ahead
                    }else{
                        // you dont have permission show toast
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            }
        }
```

[Full Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)